# Pass authentication from Apache to JBoss

Tags: apache-2.2, jboss

I have an Apache server setup that is passing requests over to a JBoss server to serve Java content.  I've been able to get this working without a problem.  However, it appears that the authentication from Apache is not being sent.

When I go to a given URL, Apache challenges me for the username/password, but when the request gets over to JBoss and I try to `getRemoteUser()`, I get nothing.  I'm pretty new to configuring any type of server (I'm a developer setting up a test environment), so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several possible solutions; if you're using mod_proxy_ajp or mod_jk for the connector then make sure that this is set in your server.xml connector:

tomcatAuthentication="false"

That will most likely fix the problem. If not, it's a bit more difficult depending on which module you're using for the AJP13 connection; we'll need to know which one before helping further.

Comment: I'm using mod_proxy_ajp.  Where would I find the `server.xml` file that I need?

By the way, I'm using JBoss 5.1 and Apache 2.2 if that helps.

Comment: it's in the conf/ subdirectory of your Tomcat engine inside the JBoss tree. This is a core piece of this framework, I recommend you brush up on how to run JBoss/Tomcat because you're going to need it to get your warballs working right (usually).